# Visual Studio 2010 IDE with Visual C++ 6.0 compiler?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010, visual-studio-6

How can I do that ? Can I work in VS2010 IDE but have it compile with the VS C++ 6.0 compiler?
And can I work in VS2010 IDE and have it compile by using the  the VS2008 compiler ?

Comment: I wouldn't know whether this is possible, but I'd really question the intention. VC6 is such a bad compiler, and TTBOMK you can switch all recent compiler versions into legacy modes if need be.

Comment: We still implement new features into our legacy application. The build process is managed by a dedicated team and is still based on the VS c++ 6.0 compiler. In order to be able to develop reliable I would like of course to be able to reproduce the exact compiling behaviour in the IDE. But if you say I can configure the VS2010 compiler to work in legacy mode, that is enough for me! How do I do that ?

Comment: Same here. Am working on a software that has it's origins ca 1993. Although some effort is done to upgrade it is not there yet. You can't just haul 10K lines of code from VC6 and hope it works. My difference that the SW I am working on is still being sold and get's new versions. My current work around, write code in VS2010 and compile in VS6. You have two IDEs open, but it works...

Answer (score 3):

you need the [Daffodil](http://daffodil.codeplex.com/) extension

Comment: This should be higher.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is possible to achieve this with VS2008 IDE and I'm 99% sure it is the same with VS2010 (but I don't have one to try with). Make a batch file in which you first need to call VCVARS32.BAT file that is included with VC++ 6.0 and then start Visual Studio with "/useenv" switch. You will then use this batch file to start Visual Studio.

.bat file:

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\Bin\VCVARS32.BAT"
start "" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /useenv
```

***NOTE**: This is path to VS2008 IDE, you need to change path for VS10 by yourself (probably just needs changing number 9 to number 10). Also if you are using 64bit OS you will need to change both paths to use "Program Files (x86)".*

Comment: This kind of works for me. I the VS2010 invokes the VS6 compiler. I just get odd command line calls. Such as `cl  ¦/`. I will need to investigate further. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: A more detailed description is found here: http://resnikb.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/using-visual-studio-2008-with-visual-c-6-0-compiler/

Answer (score 0):

Isn't possible.

You can use VS2010 C++ compiler to compile VS6 code w/o any problem.

take care about the solution will be migrated to new format (old one is saved as backup)

Answer (score 0):

Here is link below which talks about visual studio 2008 but you can refer it to execute similar steps on visual studio 2010.

http://resnikb.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/using-visual-studio-2008-with-visual-c-6-0-compiler/